# Dryer terminal block arcing

Tags: electrical, dryer

I have an electric dryer (30A, 240V) that made a "pop" sound the other day and tripped the breaker. When I reset the breaker and turned the dryer back on, I saw arcing behind the dryer. Upon investigation, it seems to be coming from the plug contacts with the dryer.

Question: how do I repair this? Do I just need a new dryer plug? Do I also need to replace the contacts on the dryer?

[image: Picture of dryer plug contacts with dryer]

Comment: Turn the breaker off now if you haven't already. Tell us what the plug prongs look like.

Comment: As in the shape the prongs are in or the condition of them?

Comment: I was interested in the condition of the prongs to get a sense of the condition of the receptacle, but since you posted a pic of the terminal block, I'll assume that's your only problem. More knowledgeable folks will chime in, but I think you need a new block and a new cord.

Comment: To clarify, we're not looking at the plug (receptacle), but the connection block on the dryer. Right? I was confused at first.

Comment: The picture is the back of the dryer, not the wall connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worth just replacing - it'd be too much risk to try and reuse it now.

It appears to have been a loose or bent screw or connection on the left terminal. Replace the block, check the wires to ensure that they aren't fried (they appear to be fine from here), and reconnect.

Comment: To clarify, should I replace the dryer block (the black plastic separator?) and the plug (being the outlet to dryer terminal)? Or just the dryer block?

Comment: From what I can see, and will assume, is that the arc was isolated to the dryer block as pictured. The plug itself should be fine. If it's blackened as well, then replace it too. Regardless, definitely replace the dryer block at least.